# Cant run python in komodo edit version 11?

Tags: python, komodoedit

I don't get any output in command output, or in the console when I change that in run command properties.

[image: The python script][image: The run command]

Edit: Added more pictures to show preferences...

[image: preferences]

[image: preferencespy]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this question is resulting from this now (in my mind) notorious LinkedIn tutorial that someone wrote that doesn't work.  Please see the forum post in our community forums that should solve this: https://community.komodoide.com/t/env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file/4316/11

Note: the original title of the post isn't related to your question but i'm pretty sure it is eventually answered in that thread.